# Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin: 3.2:sonar

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, maven-cobertura-plugin

Can anyone help me in getting solution for the below error.

Below are the version of the components to configure

1. SonarQube 5.1.2
2. Soanr-Runner 2.4
3. Java 1.7 [ **I have to use 1.7 only since my code supports only 1.7**]
4. mavn 3.3.9
5. sonar-cobertura-plugin-1.6.3
6. sonar-findbugs-plugin-3.3
7. cobertura 2.6

**Execution command**

```
mvn -fn -e org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:RELEASE:sonar -Dsonar.jdbc.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useConfigs=maxPerformance" -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000 -DskipTests
```

**In Console Window I am getting  error**

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:
3.2:sonar (default-cli) on project NWT_Core: Execution default-cli of goal org.s
onarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar failed: Unable to load the
 mojo 'sonar' in the plugin 'org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.
2' due to an API incompatibility: org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.excep
tion.ComponentLookupException: org/sonarsource/scanner/maven/SonarQubeMojo : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Regardless of what you *compile* your code with, the SonarQube analysis should be *run* with a specific Java version.
You simply need to use *different JDK versions* for the **compilation** and **analysis**.

- For **SonarQube 6.*** compatibility], make sure the JAVA_HOME=/path/to/**java8**
- For **SonarQube 9.*** compatibility], make sure the JAVA_HOME=/path/to/**java11**

Comment: Sure @G. Ann - SonarSource Team I will check this method and update back Thanks!!

Comment: Thanks It worked like charm by installing Java 8 !! Now I wanted a permanent solution Where
My Code should compile with 1.7 and my SonarQube should with Java 8 How can i do that -target 1.7 can you please help me with this.

Comment: Will this work with Java 17 as well? Getting issue for java 17: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.9.1.2184:sonar: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null

Answer (score 10):

Since the 3.2, the SonarQube maven plugin requires Java 8.
You have to use the 3.0.2 version for Java 7.

You have to explicitely add this statement to your pom :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
</plugin>
```

Because if you do not do so, by default this plugin uses the LATEST version of the plugin (3.2), hence your error.

See http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/HOME/Frequently+Asked+Questions#FrequentlyAskedQuestions-ShouldIlockversionofSonarQubeMavenplugininmypom.xml?

Comment: Still I am getting same error `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:
3.2:sonar (default-cli) on project NWT_Core: Execution default-cli of goal org.s
onarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar failed: Unable to load the
mojo 'sonar' in the plugin 'org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.
2' due to an API incompatibility: org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.excep
tion.ComponentLookupException: org/sonarsource/scanner/maven/SonarQubeMojo : Uns
upported major.minor version 52.0
`

Comment: Yeah I have done Clean Install but let try by doing `project-->Maven-->Update Maven Project` and update you back.

Comment: Yeah sorry my question was off topic, since this is a pure maven problem. Are you sure the pom you changed is the one that is used to run the maven ? I see no reason he still uses the 3.2 if you specified you want the 3.0.2 plugin. Are you sure the plugin snippet you added is active ? in a real build and not only pluginManagement, and in an active profile ?

Comment: Yeah even I am wondering why this occurring but as @ G. Ann said it working by installing Java 8 Thanks for the quick answer  !! I have up voted  your answer.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had a parent pom with

```
<build>
  <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.sonar</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

I've added my own version also within `pluginManagement` in my child pom but this didn't work I had to add the plugin to the `<build><plugins>` nodes instead of `<build><pluginManagement><plugins>`. Only then new newer version had been used.

Maybe this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, install Sonorqube.5.12 image in docker and push the project into Sonorqube. Initially we were facing some maven console errors like **major.minor version 52.0**.

Later, has been fixed by below step's for me.

**Add this plugs in maven.**

```
  <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Next, Add default DB setup in ~/.m2/settings.xml file

```
 <profile>
    <id>sonar</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <sonar.jdbc.url>jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/sonar</sonar.jdbc.url>
            <sonar.host.url>http://localhost:9000</sonar.host.url>
            <sonar.jdbc.username>sonar</sonar.jdbc.username>
            <sonar.jdbc.password>sonar</sonar.jdbc.password>
            <sonar.pdf.username>admin</sonar.pdf.username>
            <sonar.pdf.password>admin</sonar.pdf.password>
        </properties>
    </profile>
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me after using Maven->update project , `mvn clean install`, `mvn clean compile`

Answer (score 0):

I tried the below and it's working by my side.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0.2131</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>prepare-agent</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>report</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <skipTests>true</skipTests>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
```

Then

```
mvn clean org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent install
```

Then

```
mvn sonar:sonar
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had to manually go into sonarcloud and choose Analyze New Project