# Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, static-analysis, sonarqube-scan

In order to achieve static code analysis, I followed - https://dzone.com/articles/source-code-analysis-testing-technique-using-sonar and when I hit - `mvn sonar:sonar`, it resulted into error -

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar (default-
cli) on project testing: Error 500 on http://localhost:9000/api/ce/submit?
`projectKey=org.test:testing&projectName=testing -> [Help 1]
```

I googled this but nothing helped to resolved. I also tried answers of [Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin: 3.2:sonar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40300653/failed-to-execute-goal-org-sonarsource-scanner-mavensonar-maven-plugin-3-2son) but no luck.

Above error says 500 on http://localhost:9000/api/ce/submit?projectKey=org.test:testing&projectName=testing and when I open this url in browser it gives -

```
{"errors":[{"msg":"HTTP method POST is required"}]}
```

Could you please help to understand how this can be resolved?

Comment: is sonar qube running on http://localhost:9000 ?

Comment: Yes Vinay, it is running on http://localhost:9000/

Comment: Can you post the complete error trace ? and also pom.xml

Comment: There are no more logs in console. It starts with what I've mentioned in test but after that it has following but I think that won't help to find out cause - `[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException`

Comment: Any clues in the SonarQube logs?